# What is status of Raspberry Pi 5 Ubuntu 22.04 Image

Tags: system-installation, 22.04, raspberrypi

Is there an install image for Ubuntu 22.04 Desktop for Raspberry Pi 5?

Answer (score 6):

The status of Raspberry Pi images can be found on [the Ubuntu website](https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi). As you can see, the Pi 5 is not supported for Ubuntu 22.04, but is supported on Ubuntu 23.10.

[image]

Comment: Thats a surprising situation considering UB23.10 is LTE Jan 24, i.e now. And that 10,000’s ROS 2 Developers use Ub22.04 with Humble distribution that is LTE in 2027. There is no ROS 2 distribution that uses Ub23

Comment: Here's the problem. The new RP5 Ubuntu 23.10 is nearly  EOL             23.10  (Mantic Minotaur)       Oct 2023 Jul 2024  
23.04 (Lunar Lobster)              Apr 2023 Jan 2024  
22.04 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)    Apr 2022 Apr 2027